# App was rejected due to crash but i cannot reproduce it?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

Can anyone help figuring out what is causing this crash. Here is the code that is causing the crash. I've only tested on iPhone and the app store tested on iPad could this be device specific.

When I submit it for review it gets rejected for reason "Performance - 2.1" - app crash for them on first view.

Here is crash log Apple review team sent:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010003b160 Termination Signal: Trace/BPT
>   trap: 5 Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5 Terminating
>   Process: exc handler [0] Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   Playlist Cheetah                 0x000000010003b160
>   CreatePlaylistVC.updateSong() -> () (CreatePlaylistVC.swift:0) 1
>   Playlist Cheetah                  0x0000000100040108 specialized
>   CreatePlaylistVC.drag(gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> ()
>   (CreatePlaylistVC.swift:253) 2   Playlist Cheetah
>     0x000000010003ac84 @objc CreatePlaylistVC.drag(gesture :
>   UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> () (CreatePlaylistVC.swift:0) 3   UIKit
>     0x0000000194eecc54 0x19490b000 + 6167636 4   UIKit
>     0x0000000194ef0488 0x19490b000 + 6182024 5   UIKit
>     0x0000000194aaa540 0x19490b000 + 1701184 6   UIKit
>     0x000000019494c45c 0x19490b000 + 267356 7   UIKit
>     0x0000000194ee072c 0x19490b000 + 6117164 8   UIKit
>     0x0000000194ee02fc 0x19490b000 + 6116092 9   UIKit
>     0x0000000194edf5a8 0x19490b000 + 6112680 10  UIKit
>     0x000000019494a7e8 0x19490b000 + 260072 11  UIKit
>     0x000000019491b418 0x19490b000 + 66584 12  UIKit
>     0x0000000195114f64 0x19490b000 + 8429412 13  UIKit
>     0x000000019510f6c0 0x19490b000 + 8406720 14  UIKit
>     0x000000019510f9a0 0x19490b000 + 8407456 15  UIKit
>     0x000000019510faec 0x19490b000 + 8407788 16  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018e7a1424 0x18e6c6000 + 898084 17  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018e7a0d94 0x18e6c6000 + 896404 18  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018e79e9a0 0x18e6c6000 + 887200 19  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018e6ced94 0x18e6c6000 + 36244 20  GraphicsServices
>     0x0000000190138074 0x19012c000 + 49268 21  UIKit
>     0x0000000194980130 0x19490b000 + 479536 22  Playlist Cheetah
>     0x00000001000322f0 main (ApiConvience.swift:12) 23  libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018d6dd59c 0x18d6d9000 + 17820
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d7eda88
>   0x18d7ce000 + 129672 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b3274 0x18d8b2000 + 4724 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b2d7c 0x18d8b2000 + 3452
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d7eda88
>   0x18d7ce000 + 129672 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b3274 0x18d8b2000 + 4724 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b2d7c 0x18d8b2000 + 3452
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d7eda88
>   0x18d7ce000 + 129672 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b30a0 0x18d8b2000 + 4256 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b2d7c 0x18d8b2000 + 3452
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d8b2d78
>   0x18d8b2000 + 3448
>
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d7eda88
>   0x18d7ce000 + 129672 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b30a0 0x18d8b2000 + 4256 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b2d7c 0x18d8b2000 + 3452
>
> Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread Thread 6: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018d7cf224 0x18d7ce000 + 4644 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018d7cf09c 0x18d7ce000 + 4252 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018e7a0e88 0x18e6c6000 + 896648
>   3   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018e79eadc 0x18e6c6000 +
>   887516 4   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018e6ced94
>   0x18e6c6000 + 36244 5   Foundation
>     0x000000018f1e8d64 0x18f1dc000 + 52580 6   Foundation
>     0x000000018f209b34 0x18f1dc000 + 187188 7   UIKit
>     0x000000019530a5f8 0x19490b000 + 10483192 8   Foundation
>     0x000000018f2e62c8 0x18f1dc000 + 1090248 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 
>     0x000000018d8b575c 0x18d8b2000 + 14172 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b566c 0x18d8b2000 + 13932 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018d8b2d84 0x18d8b2000 + 3460
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
>       x0: 0x0000000100813e40   x1: 0x00000001954fdaa9   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
>       x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000007   x7: 0x0000000000000570
>       x8: 0x00000001740efe00   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000006  x11: 0x0000000000000000    x12: 0x0000000101897a90
>   x13: 0x000005a100075d3f  x14: 0x0000000000b27800  x15:
>   0x0000000000b277c0    x16: 0x0000000100075d38  x17: 0x0000000195190d68
>   x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000101838c00    x20:
>   0x0000000100813e40  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000195458c72 
>   x23: 0x0000000100074000    x24: 0x0000000100074000  x25:
>   0x0000000100074000  x26: 0x0000000100074000  x27: 0x00000000000002f8
>   x28: 0x0000000000000358   fp: 0x000000016fdd0df0   lr:
>   0x000000010003af68
>       sp: 0x000000016fdd0da0   pc: 0x000000010003b160 cpsr: 0x60000000

```
func updateSong() {
        if suggestionsSwitch.isOn && similarSongsArray.count > 0 {

            let randIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((similarSongsArray.count))))
            currentIndex = randIndex

            let song = similarSongsArray[currentIndex]

            showingSimilarSong = true
            AlbumImgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "noAlbumArt")
            songTitleLbl.text = song.title
            albumTitleLbl.text = song.artist
        } else {
        let randIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((songsArr.count))))

        currentIndex = randIndex

        showingSimilarSong = false
        AlbumImgView.image = songsArr[currentIndex].artwork
        songTitleLbl.text = songsArr[currentIndex].title
        albumTitleLbl.text = songsArr[currentIndex].album

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: Any chance songsArr[] is empty?

Comment: @Spads I doubt it. It doesn't crash on any of my devices

Comment: Erm, "It doesn't crash for me" is a classic coder response. Think what is filling the array songsArr, is there anyway that array gets filled with nothing or gets emptied at a later date.

Comment: of course I could be barking up the wrong tree, not having complete code etc. But that is the only situation I can see not being checked for.

Comment: few years ago, my reviewer rejected the app due to the crash in the first view that i cannot reproduce. I've got rejected three times, so then I sent a  link of a video showing the app working just fine. After that, my reviewer gave up and decided to register my app to the AppStore (seriously, i didn't even fix the issue). Surprisingly, I was able to reproduce the crash right after I ran the app that was installed from the AppStore, not from the XCode. - Just sharing my story.

Comment: Have you tried a TestFlight build?

Comment: @Spads You're right I added some additional error handling just in case.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes but not on an iPad because I don't own one

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but i think according to your crash log, you need to check where you **dragged** something during **playlist creation** and where **pan-gesture** has been used.Try drag that thing to the boundary and code snippet regarding this.